# Net Core custom controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

Currently my code looks something like this:

```
public class UserController : ControllerBase
{

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginCredentialsModel model)
    {
       if (someValidLogic){
           return Ok(new { message = "User login success.", 
                           additionalParameters = new { 
                                    param1 = "",
                                    param2 = ""
                            }
                          });
       }
        else {
           return BadRequest(new { errorMessage = "Username or password is incorrect.", 
                                   additionalParameters = {
                                       StatusCode = 400, 
                                       RetryLeftCount = 3 }
                                   });
        }  
    }

}
```

I am manually creating JSON objects to return to UI in every endpoint so that I can have consistent communication and allow UI to handle messages at a global level. (using angular interceptors in my case). I am wanting to create a custom class that can be implemented by all controllers that have only two options of return types - Success(), Fail().

```
public class UserController : CustomControllerBase
{

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginCredentialsModel model)
    {
       if (someValidLogic){
           return Success("User login success.", additionalParameters)
       }
       else {
           return Error("Username or password is incorrect.", additionalParameters);
       }  
    }

}
```

And my CustomControllerBase would be in charge of formatting the results in the proper form. I know I can do this via middleware but I really do not want to as it still allows developers to accidentally send back some non-valid results and middleware not knowing how to handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you make a custom base controller you're going to have to make the custom base controller extend Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase, else you won't get all the automatic routing, the [HttpPost] type attributes etc.  And once you extend ControllerBase, all the methods like Ok() will be available to your other developers.  I'd really just try to communicate with the developers to not use Ok() etc.

This is hacky, but you could "block" the other methods by overriding them in your CustomControllerBase and just throwing an exception.  This won't create a compile time error but it will at least create a shallow runtime exception.  Also there's a LOT of these methods and you'd have to override them all.

```
public class CustomControllerBase : ControllerBase
{
    public ActionResult Success(string message)
    {
        return base.Ok(message);
    }
    public new ActionResult Ok(object value)
    {
        throw new Exception("don't use this");
    }
}

public class UserController : CustomControllerBase
{

    public async Task<ActionResult> Hello()
    {
        return Ok("hello"); // throws runtime exception
    }
}
```

Alternatively use a style checker and outlaw all uses of Ok() and similar methods.  You'd also have to disallow lines like `return new OkObjectResult("hello");`  It's really going to be quite an ordeal to get this right.

Answer (score 1):

As you've requested, to have a custom class that you can re-use in returning response messages back to the calling request, I created a custom class that inherits from `ActionResult` that we can return.

After having this class in place, we are going to use it to create a base/custom controller where we will add our `Success` and `Fail` methods which any controller can inherit from to use the extended methods.

### CustomActionResult

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text

/// <summary>
/// Customized <see cref="ActionResult"/> that allows easily setting <see cref="HttpStatusCode"/>
/// and data result object to be returned for a request.
/// </summary>
public class CustomActionResult : ActionResult
{
    private static UTF8Encoding utf = new UTF8Encoding();

    /// <summary>
    /// Http response code.
    /// </summary>
    public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Data to return back to the user as an <see cref="object"/> of any <see cref="Type"/>
    /// </summary>
    public object Data { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Parameterless contructor that initializes the ActionResult with
    /// <see cref="HttpStatusCode.OK"/> as the default Response Code.
    /// </summary>
    public CustomActionResult()
    {
        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
        Headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor that initializes the ActionResult with a specified <see cref="HttpStatusCode"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="statusCode">
    /// Http response code to set for this ActionResult.
    /// </param>
    public CustomActionResult(HttpStatusCode statusCode)
        :this()
    {
        StatusCode = statusCode;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor that initializes the ActionResult with a specified <see cref="HttpStatusCode"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="statusCode">
    /// Http response code to set for this ActionResult.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="message">Reason phrase</param>
    public CustomActionResult(HttpStatusCode statusCode, string message)
        :this()
    {
        StatusCode = statusCode;
        Data = message;
    }


    private string Json
    {
        get
        {
            if(Data != null)
            {
                if (Data.GetType() == typeof(string))
                {
                    return Data.ToString();
                }
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Data);
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }

    public byte[] GetBuffer() => utf.GetBytes(Json);

    public Dictionary<string,string> Headers { get; private set; }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ActionContext context)
    {
        if (Headers.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Headers.Count; i++)
            {
                var item = Headers.ElementAt(i);
                context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
            }
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Json))
        {
            context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        }

        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)StatusCode;
        context.HttpContext.Response.Body.Write(GetBuffer(), 0, GetBuffer().Length);
    }
}
```

### CustomBaseController

```
public class CustomBaseController : ControllerBase
{
    public ActionResult Success(object value)
    {
        return new CustomActionResult(){ Data = value };
    }
    public ActionResult Success(string message, params object[] additionalParams)
    {
        if(additionalParams.Length > 0){
            return new CustomActionResult(){
                Data = new { message, additionalParams }
            };
        }else{
            return new CustomActionResult() { Data = message };
        }
    }
    public ActionResult Fail(object value)
    {
        return new CustomActionResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest){ Data = value };
    }
    public ActionResult Fail(string message, params object[] additionalParams)
    {
        if(additionalParams.Length > 0){
            return new CustomActionResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest){
                Data = new { ErrorMessage = message, additionalParams }
            };
        }else{
            return new CustomActionResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest){
                Data = new { ErrorMessage = message }
            };
        } 
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
public class UserController : CustomBaseController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginCredentialsModel model)
    {
        if(!ModelState.IsValid)
            return this.Fail(ModelState);

        // add your other custom logic here
        if(someLogic){
            return this.Success("your-message", additionalParams);
        } else {
            return this.Fail("custom-error-message", additionalParams);
        }
    }
}
```